# How can i add username from firestore into my appbar in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So i have been trying to make an app in flutter, but i cannot seem to succeed in getting the username from the firestore database into a variable
Here is my code!!
**EDIT:**

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<String> inputData() async {
  String _username = '';
  final userCol = Firestore.instance.collection("users");
  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
  final uid = user.uid;

  // here you write the codes to input the data into firestorenull
  final data = await userCol.document(uid).get().then(
    (value) {
      final username = value.data["username"];
      _username = username;
      
    },
  );
  return _username;
}
```

I have tried it in many many different ways, as async, as future, with FutureBuilder etc but i cannot seem to find the solution.
Here is the appbar:

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Scaffold(
          appBar: appbar.ProfileAppBar(name: _username)
............................................................
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information (such as whether or not you are successfully retrieving the username and it is getting properly set), but it looks like you aren't setting the state of the screen after getting the username.

Can you try

```
setState(() {
  final username = docs.data["username"];
  this._username = username;
});
```

Your function also appears to be incorrect. You are defining username as an empty string, and then defining an asynchronous function to get the username, and immediately returning username (the empty string). You will need to use a class variable and inside of the setstate, set the class variable as what you get from your asyncronous '.then()' function

Comment: I have actually tried it and it retrieves the username correctly, can you please elaborate on the last paragraph you wrote?

Comment: So, you define username as an empty string, then you are creating a thread that is waiting for the result from your api call. But the function is not waiting for that result (because you are not using await) instead you are using .then(), which creates a seperate thread. So immediately after you create the thread, you are returning username (which is still an empty string, because your api call hasn't returned yet). You should instead have the api call set the class attribute that your appbar is referencing (_username) inside of a setState, so that the UI updates

Comment: I changed my code to another attempt i had tried before, i have a feeling that the setState will fix everything, i am just not certain of where to put it

Comment: you want to put it wherever you are updating the variable that modifies the appbars title. Currently you are using the private variable '_username' so whenever you update '_username' it should be inside of a setState function to let the UI know it needs to redraw with the updated username

Answer (score 0):

So what i in fact did was to create a FutureBuilder, which helped a lot and i recommend it to everyone!!!